# Why was this question, to which I provided a good answer, "removed for reasons of moderation"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, deleted-questions, moderation

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529097/mistake-with-null-comparison-in-c/) question (image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMvVv.png)) was recently removed for moderation reasons. I lost 70 rep for my answer which also went away with the question. The question was very much answerable in SO format. I'm clueless as to why it was removed.

Can the moderator kindly explain why it was removed?
(If it was a duplicate, it could have been closed instead of being deleted, thereby saving my rep :))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OP flagged and asked for it to be deleted.

He essentially said that he made a stupid mistake, and that the problem was in another part of his program.

We get lots of flags like this, but we don't really have any strict guidelines for what to do in these situations.  Therefore it is up to the moderator's discretion if he/she deletes.

Now, we (in general) *don't* want to delete good content, as good questions/answers is what StackOverflow is all about.  Since the OP asked a bad/incorrect/pointless/localized question, this tips the balance in favor of deletion.  I believe this is what the deleting moderator took into account when they deleted the question.

I, on the other hand, disagree.

In general, I don't particularly care if the OP thinks they have asked a stupid question.  I believe that if the question cannot be self-deleted due to system rules, or if the question has any value whatsoever, then question should stand.  A good answer is a valid reason for the question to stand.  If the OP complains about getting downvoted or being embarrassed, tough tittay.  As I like to say, **it shall stand as a shining beacon to remind you *never to do this again***.

Since there is value to be had in its entirety (namely, your answer and the rep you gained for your efforts), I've undeleted.

Comment: I wish people who had the idea of SE moderators as some sort of monolithic overlord would see the regular examples like this of both the moderation system and the moderators themselves working just like they should. Kudos.

Answer (score 13):

This question doesn't look *great* to me, but it *does* look acceptable. There is an actual problem to solve, and there is a simple, self-contained example that reliably reproduces the problem. Furthermore, your answer is quite good, even more so considering that lots of people have this same problem. I wouldn't have deleted it.

I notice that it was deleted *without being closed*, so that makes me think that the asker flagged it for deletion directly, and a moderator complied with his request. You'll have to get the moderator who deleted it to confirm that.

Comment: "that makes me think that the asker flagged it for deletion directly" - also the asker received the 'first flag' badge 9 minutes after asking the question...

Comment: Well, by nature the moderator really can't say .. because flags are private. However, we don't directly delete questions with great answers without a compelling reason, and I don't disagree with a single thing you wrote in this answer (I'm not the mod that serviced that particular flag).

Comment: @TimPost Cant other mods undelete it? Or only the same mod has to do it? And can other mods know which mod took action?

Comment: @PavanManjunath Any mod can undo any action by any other mod (barring recovering a deleted account), however undeleting the question in this instance isn't going to help much. If I undeleted it, I'd also need to close it (as it is way too localized), and it would likely be deleted again in the space of a few days.

Answer (score 3):

The question is a "what is wrong with this code" question - this is not a good question for StackExchange because it is too localized.

By this I mean that the only person it can help is the OP. No one else will benefit from it.

Comment: Hmm.. The OP had indeed indicated that he is getting a crash/seg fault if I remember properly and not just pasted the code? And when we are not able to see the mistakes in our code, its not wrong to ask for help right? The Qn/answer related to difference between NULL and a null/empty string which will surely help others too

Comment: @PavanManjunath: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UMvVv.png